# postfix reject incoming mail for certain recipients

Tags: postfix

I administer an email server based on Postfix that has copies of past emails as well as current ones.  Some of the users have left but their email history needs to be retained and accessible.  In the present situation, any emails to those users that hav left are still received as normal.  I want to block any new emails to those accounts.  I can see a way of doing that using smtpd_restriction_classes.  Would I have to include all users in the check_recipient_access hash table or can I just include those accounts I want to block?

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = restrictive, permissive
restrictive = DEFER
permissive = permit
check_recipient_access = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access

/etc/postfix/recipient_access:
    joe@example.com  restrictive
    mary@example.com restrictive
```

Answer (score 8):

It seems this blocking is intended to be permanent. If you use `DEFER`, Postfix will send temporary error code `450`, causing the sending MTA to try again later. From [RFC 5321, 4.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.2.1) & 4.2.2:

> `4yz`  Transient Negative Completion reply
>
> The command was not accepted, and the requested action did not
> occur.  However, the error condition is temporary, and the action
> may be requested again.  The sender should return to the beginning
> of the command sequence (if any).  It is difficult to assign a
> meaning to "transient" when two different sites (receiver- and
> sender-SMTP agents) must agree on the interpretation.  Each reply
> in this category might have a different time value, but the SMTP
> client SHOULD try again.
>
> ```
> 450  Requested mail action not taken: mailbox unavailable (e.g.,
>    mailbox busy or temporarily blocked for policy reasons)
>
> 550  Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable (e.g., mailbox
>    not found, no access, or command rejected for policy reasons)
> ```

I'd use error code `550`, default for permanent `REJECT` being [`access_map_reject_code`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#access_map_reject_code)`= 554`.

Then, the `check_recipient_access` doesn't work alone, but within [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions).

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    . . .
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access,
    . . .
```

In addition to the error code you can use a custom human readable, informational error message:

```
/etc/postfix/recipient_access:
    joe@example.com   550  Mailbox doesn't exist. See https://example.com/contact
    mary@example.com  550  Mary no longer works at Example Ltd. Contact Jason, instead.
```

As it's a `hash:` database, always remember to `postmap /etc/postfix/recipient_access`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This has achieved what I wanted to do.

Comment: Please acccept my answer if it worked for you. :)

Comment: I don't have a high enough score so I don't see an Accept box.

Comment: According to http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html you NEED to add a human readable error message for numeric 'actions' to work. This is also what I experienced. So please do not forget it. ;)
@EsaJokinen Maybe you can update your answer accordingly :)