# Multiple problems when trying to set up a no-reply email adress

Tags: email, postfix, email-bounces

I have an email server setup using Postfix, Dovecot and MySQL with virtual mailboxes using PostfixAdmin. This was created following a tutorial, because I am fairly new to email servers, and everything is working really well.

I wanted to make a no-reply email address for purposes like sending newsletter-esque emails that people can't reply to. I first tried this by creating a new mailbox with a quota of 0 MB, this did not seem to work because I could still receive emails in that mailbox. I could not find another way to do this via PostfixAdmin, so I searched the internet on how to do this. I came across some solutions that suggest routing all emails received at that address to `/dev/null`. I tried this, and at first it did not seem to work correctly, so I reverted the changes I made. I later found out that this was because I didn't do it correctly (there was an alias set for the no-reply address to go to devnull, and then that should have been routed to `/dev/null`, via a different file that I did not set properly. This resulted in the email becoming undeliverable and a failure bounce from the email server that ended up in my spam folder, which I did not notice at the time).

Later on, I figured this could maybe be useful, since I've seen before that I get such a reply when trying to reply to a no-reply email address. However, I would like to change certain parts of the default message, so I looked up if there was a way to change this. I came across multiple sources (e.g. the [Postfix docs](https://www.postfix.org/bounce.5.html)) saying roughly the same, that there should be a file `/etc/postfix/bounce.cf.default`, which you can then copy and edit accordingly. The issue is, I don't have this file somehow. I did find a seemingly older version of the file [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/configure-custom-postfix-bounce-messages) (older because the failure message differs from the one I got). I could copy this of course and use it as a template, but I find it strange that I don't have this file (at least not in the right location), and curious where it's actually located.

Another question I have, is what would be the best way to configure a no-reply email in Postfix/Dovecot? Because maybe this way of making all emails undeliverable and bounce is a bit hacky and too much hassle. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following solution from an older post.

How to reject incoming messages for specific recipients and add a custom reply:
[postfix reject incoming mail for certain recipients](https://serverfault.com/questions/919458/postfix-reject-incoming-mail-for-certain-recipients)

Comment: Just tried this, and it seems to work, which is great. It does not bounce the email however, but I don't know whether that's really necessary, but I suppose it could be useful to notify users. But thanks, because this at least solves the no-reply problem, which was my biggest concern.